# How do I implement hooks/filters/actions within my application?

Tags: c#

We have customers that often have varying requests. Currently, we do things such as `if customer_code = ? then ...` and do something different just for that customer.

I want to employ something similar to how Wordpress/Magento works where you can subscribe to events, receive the data, process it how you want and then return control back to the application.

I want to store this customer specific functionality inside of an assembly specific to that customer. Note, I don't want to completely override the method, just points within the method to do things (in most instances anyway).

Examples are:
- Before order placed
- After order placed
- Before allocation
- After allocation
- After status change

Comment: Take a look on the [Template Method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this in C#. Here are a couple of them:

[C# events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx) are extensively used by Win Forms and Web Forms. These feel very much like interrupt handlers, but in reality are just delegates (function pointers).

```
// Declaration
public event EventHandler BeforeOrderPlaced;
public event EventHandler AfterOrderPlaced;

// Raising events
public void ProcessOrder()
{
    if (BeforeOrderPlaced != null)
        BeforeOrderPlaced(this, new EventArgs());

    PlaceOrder();

    if (AfterOrderPlaced != null)
        AfterOrderPlaced(this, new EventArgs());
}

// Subscribe to events
BeforeOrderPlaced += MyHandler;

private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do something before the order is placed
}
```

[C# virtual methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645767(v=vs.71).aspx) is the object-oriented approach.

```
public class OrderSystem
{
    // Defaults - do nothing
    public virtual void BeforeOrderPlaced() {}
    public virtual void AfterOrderPlaced() {}

    public void ProcessOrder()
    {
        BeforeOrderPlaced();
        PlaceOrder();
        AfterOrderPlaced();
    }
}

// Override the defaults to insert code before/after placing the order.
public class MyOrderSystem : OrderSystem
{
    public override void BeforeOrderPlaced()
    {
        // do something before the order is placed
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are talking about is known as [multitenancy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitenancy).

Here's one way to do it:

1. Implement basic functionality in non-sealed classes with key methods defined as virtual.  Let's imagine for this example that all of your business logic is in a class called `BaseBusinessLogic` and there is a method called `DoSomething()`.
2. For customer-specific functionality, write classes that inherit from the basic classes, overriding virtual methods as needed.  If Kodak is one of your customers, maybe the class might be defined as `class KodakBusinessLogic : BaseBusinessLogic`.
3. Create a database table which maps tenants (perhaps identified by `customer_code`) onto DLLs and classes.  There would be 3 columns:

   customer_code - Whatever datatype you use

   custom_assembly - The name of the DLL, e.g. `KodakBusinessLibrary.dll`

   class_name - The name of the derived class that contains the customer-specific logic (e.g. `KodakBusinessLogic`)
4. When you need to run functionality that may be customer-specific, call a stored procedure to obtain custom_assembly and class_name for that customer_code.

Then you can instantiate the derived class like this:

```
var asm = Assembly.LoadFile(custom_assembly);
var type = asm.GetType(class_name);
var o = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as BaseBusinessLogic;
if (o == null) throw new Exception("Couldn't load the custom logic.");
```

And run the customer-specific logic like this:

```
o.DoSomething();
```

Even though you have a reference to a BaseBusinessLogic, in reality that pointer is pointing at a KodakBusinessLogic, and calling DoSomething will execute the overridden method that contains the logic for Kodak.

Now, if you don't want to override the method itself, you can define things like this:

```
class BaseBusinessLogic
{
    public void DoSomething() //notice it's not virtual
    {
        this.OnBeforeProcessing();
        //Execute basic logic here
        this.OnAfterProcessing();
    }

    abstract void OnBeforeProcessing();
    abstract void OnAfterProcessing();
}
```

Then in your derived class, you just need to override OnBeforeProcessing and OnAfterProcessing.